# Symmetric property of a binary relation

Tags: definition, relations

A binary relation $\mathcal R$ on $E$ with graph $G$ is symmetric if and only if $\forall(x,y)\in E^2,\,x\mathcal R y\implies y\mathcal R x$.

Suppose that $\mathcal R$ is symmetric. By definition, $G\subset E^2$. So, if I take a random element $(x,y)$ of $E^2$, and find that it is in $G$, then I would know that $(y,x)$ is also in $G$. But if I happen to fall on $(y,x)$ first, wouldn't I conclude that $(x,y)\in G$, too? Which means that the definition should have an equivalence symbol, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The definition is what you wrote, and then you deduced from it that$$\left(\forall (x,y)\in E^2\right):x\mathrel{\mathcal R}y\iff y\mathrel{\mathcal R}x.\tag1$$But that doesn't make the definition wrong somehow. It only means that if we had decided to adopt $(1)$ has the definition, nothing would change.

Comment: thank you! but is there a reason why people decided on using implication rather than equivalence in the definition? it seems like equivalence saves an obvious step, and, as you said, it contains the $\implies$.

Comment: The general principle is that if you want to pick between several choices for a definition, you pick the one which has less things to check.